# Is there a standard Kotlin function to return a list without the item at a given index?

Tags: kotlin

I need to remove an item from a list without mutating it.

I can write my own:

```
fun <T> Iterable<T>.withoutItemAt(index: Int): List<T> =
    take(index) + drop(index + 1)
```

but it feels like this should be in the standard library.

Is there such a function?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`filterIndexed`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-indexed.html):

```
fun <T> Iterable<T>.withoutItemAt(index: Int): List<T> =
    filterIndexed { i, _ -> i != index }
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is something like this in the standard library, I'm afraid.

There's [`Iterable.minus()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/minus.html), which can remove a given *element*, but I can't see anything for removing a given *index*.

It may seem an obvious addition — and I'm sure it would be easy for them to add — but it may not be commonly needed.  (I can't recall ever wanting it.)  For many uses, I suspect a mutable list (which has a [`removeAt()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/remove-at.html) function) might be more suitable.

By the way, here's an alternative implementation, that's likely to be more efficient:

```
fun <L> Iterable<L>.withoutItemAt(index: Int)
    = filterIndexed{ i, _ -> i != index }
```

Comment: I like "likely to be more efficient"! My drop version is horrendous, as it copies twice.
I think that inlining `filterIndexed` and using the collection size if we have it to pre-initialise the ArrayList could make this the best bet overall.

Comment: Although I'm tempted to write a List version that just creates a view rather than any copies